# org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.ReferenceExpression cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_1.3.0.rap-20200811-0954

Tags: java, eclipse

I have updated Target platform for our RAP Application to Eclipse version 2020-09. Now I can't start the application because of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException :

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.ReferenceExpression cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_1.3.0.rap-20200811-0954
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.MenuManagerRenderer.processContributions(MenuManagerRenderer.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.MenuManagerRenderer.createWidget(MenuManagerRenderer.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:952)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:642)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:701)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1024)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.rap.e4.E4EntryPointFactory.createWorkbench(E4EntryPointFactory.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.rap.e4.E4EntryPointFactory.access$0(E4EntryPointFactory.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.rap.e4.E4EntryPointFactory$1.createUI(E4EntryPointFactory.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle.createUI(RWTLifeCycle.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.RWTLifeCycle$UIThreadController.run(RWTLifeCycle.java:290)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.rap.rwt.internal.lifecycle.UIThread.run(UIThread.java:107)
```

With the older Eclipse version 2020-06 it works fine. Is it any Eclipse Bug or need I any additional dependency? Any advice?

Comment: The `ReferenceExpression` class appears to have been moved in the current release. So it looks like `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_1.3.0.rap-20200811-0954` is out of date.

Comment: You are right greg-449, I had checked the structure of org.eclipse.core.expressions and in the release 3.7.0.v20200720-1126 was the class ReferenceExpression (and also other classes) moved from org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions to org.eclipse.core.expressions.